# Using Javascript to apply CSS3 transition for transform/translate property

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

Just trying to get this image to animate the transform property, by editing the CSS3 properties via JS.

By clicking the 'test' button, the expected result is the image to animate left 100 pixels.

It currently just goes to that position immediately and I get this error in the console:

`Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function`

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/PzAxu/8/

Comment: remove the call to "test()" in the onclick="" attribute. It isn't defined.

Comment: You should take a look at this awesome plugin: http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

Comment: @victorswx ah that was left in there from before, removing it doesn't help though.  I would use a plugin like that but this is for an actual plugin too, and I'd rather learn to write it from scratch.